# boost serialization: update member when deserialized

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have an object that I am serializing with boost archive. The object has a member of type `boost::math::normal_distribution<double> distribution`, however boost do not supply a serialize method for this type so instead I serialize the mean and standard deviation. My serialize function looks like:

```
template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(mean);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(std);
    }
```

When the object is de-serialized, I want to make a re-create the distribution with these parameters (as the default is constructed with mean 0 and std 1). Where do I put this code? In the constructor?

Thanks

Comment: you could split the save and load functions (BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER) and in the load method you can instantiate the distribution after you have the mean and std.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the current implementation of normal_distribution is serializable because it does not have any means to set it's values after it's construction.

A workaround could be allocating normal_distribution on the heap and use the saver/loader-pattern instead of one serialize-function like it is documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#splitting

In the loader you can construct normal_distribution with new and the loaded parameters.